# GetObject set to ArrayObject C#

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

I am new to C# programming.I have created a Cell Class that x and y positions and Warrior Object. Warrior with (int hitpoints, int defensePoint)

```
 public class Cell
     {
         public int _x;
         public int _y;
         public Warrior _warrior;
     }
```

and I am using

```
   public void setWarrior(Warrior warrior) {
        this.warrior = _warrior;
   }
```

to `setWarrior` to specific cells

now, I want to `getWarrior` that I have set to specific Cell.

```
  public Warrior getWarrior(int X, int Y)
     {
         return _warrior;
     }

 Cell[,] cells = new Cell[6, 6];  
 Warrior magicWarrior1 = new Warrior();
 cells[2,3].setWarrior(magicWarrior1); 
 Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", cells[2,3].warrior);
 cells[2,3].getWarrior(2,3);
 Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", cells[2,3].warrrior);
```

But this doesn't work.
Problem: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

How to find the warrior Object set to that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the below:

```
 public void setWarrior(Warrior warrior) {
        this.warrior = _warrior;
   }
```

it should have been:

```
 public void setWarrior(Warrior warrior) {
        this._warrior = warrior;
   }
```

This is in addition to

```
 cells[2,3] = new Cell();   //<-------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 Cell[,] cells = new Cell[6, 6];  
 Warrior magicWarrior1 = new Warrior();
 cells[2,3] = new Cell();   //<-------------
 cells[2,3].setWarrior(magicWarrior1); 
 Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", cells[2,3].warrior);
```

You haven't initialized your `Cell` object in the same way as you do for `magicWarrior1` object.